# ActiveRecord AutoIncrement Value

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am using active record with mysql on a rails web app.

After saving some active record models i noticed that the id field is being incremented by 10. Shouldn't it e by 1?

If i can change it what is the rake or activerecord migration command

Comment: Did you deleted some records from the table before? In that case it happens like this.

Comment: I didn't. I even reset the entire dev database instance. Both times the id fields keep incrementing by 10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in rails console type

**1. for postgresql**

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("ALTER SEQUENCE table_name_id_seq RESTART WITH 1")
```

**2. for mysql**

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=1")
```

where table_name is your actual table name

using migration

```
class SetAutoIncrement < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    execute "ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=1"
  end

  def self.down
  end
end
```

Comment: This works. But how do i enable this by default when i create the models?

Comment: you can do it in migration also

Comment: @RohanPanchal see the updated answer,although i have never tried like that so m not sure.